# Repository error received during an upgrade

Tags: java, ppa, jdk, oracle

```
E: Repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'Oracle Java (JDK) 8 Installer PPA' to 'Oracle Java (JDK) 8 Installer PPA (DISCONTINUED)'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

i read manpage but did not fully understand what i was to do so i did nothing...how do i resolve this issue???

Thank You

Comment: The link mentioned above will tell you how to fix when it matters. In this case just remove the ppa as it's dead, useless and empty..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add the PPA

This is done by :

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Use the 'update' command to retrieve the PPA :

```
$ sudo apt update
```

Did you get it to work now? Let me know

The way PPA's are added works a little bit different